# JPA - left join 2 tables without association

Tags: database, jpa, join, entity

I have **2 tables**/entities with **no association**.
I can go for ***cross joins*** in JPA

```
FROM A as a, B as b WHERE b.col1=a.col1
```

***How Can I perform a left-join?***

I want all values from A and fill them up with B values where possible and leave NULL where there is no B.

*Does not work:*

```
FROM A as a LEFT JOIN B as b WHERE b.col1=a.col1
```

> Path expected for join!
>
> Invalid path: 'b.col1'

Comment: This article describes how to do it with a recent Hibernate version: https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/how-to-join-unrelated-entities/

Answer (score -5, accepted):

This is possible with JPA with following query:

```
FROM A as a, B as b WHERE b.col1=a.col1 OR b.col1 IS NULL
```

Comment: That is not the same as a LEFT JOIN. Suppose you have b.col1=3 and no a.col1=3. Your query will not return this row, but a LEFT JOIN will return it.

Answer (score 10):

You cannot do that in JPA, as long as there is no relationship between the entities.

Solutions:

1. Use Native queries.
2. Add a relationship between them (eventually an indirect lazy one). With indirect I mean something like :
   A knows PseudoEntity,
   PseudoEntity knows B (but the relationship owner is entity B),
   B knows PseudoEntity.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Dimitri Dewaele's answer, this query is a CARTESIAN JOIN. The CARTESIAN JOIN or CROSS JOIN returns the Cartesian product of the sets of records from two or more joined tables. Thus, it equates to an **inner join** where the join-condition always evaluates to either True or where the join-condition is absent from the statement. If you want to read more about it, follow the link below:
[Sql Cartesian Joins](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-cartesian-joins.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you can now do this as of Hibernate 5.1

Comment: could you please share with us a snippet from the jpa query or the Jpa Api code

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using **JPQL**:

```
FROM A a LEFT JOIN B b ON b.col1=a.col1
```