# Criteria API join problem: entity which does not hold relationship column can not "join"

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, criteria-api

The required entities are roughly as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID userId;

    // Omitted other fields and getters/setters ...
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_groups")
public class Group {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer groupId;

    // ....
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_group_members")
public class GroupMember {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "group_id")
    private Group group;

    // getters & setters ...
}
```

This is a many-to-many relationship with an intermediate table:

> Group <----- 1:N -----> GroupMember <----- N:1 -----> User

The query I want to achieve (through Criteria API) is basically the same as the following JPQL:

```
select g from Group g join GroupMember gm on g = gm.group where gm.user = ? and  ...or whatever...
```

I try to construct the CriteriaQuery as follows:

```
User userToQuery = ...;
// ....
CriteriaQuery<Group> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Group.class);
Root<Group> groupRoot = query.from(Group.class);
Root<GroupMember> gmRoot = query.from(GroupMember.class);
groupRoot.join(...).on(criteriaBuilder.equal(groupRoot, gmRoot.get("group"))); // I can't find a suitable join() method to specify the relationship
Predicate predicate = criteriaBuilder.equal(gmRoot.get("user"), userToQuery);
// ......
```

Since the `Group` entity does not hold an association relationship, I do not know how to call the join(...) method.

I must declare the association in reverse, that is, from the GroupMember entity:

```
CriteriaQuery<GroupMember> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(GroupMember.class);
Root<GroupMember> gmRoot = query.from(GroupMember.class);
gmRoot.join("group");
// ......
```

Does JPA's Criteria API have this restriction?
How does an entity that does not contain an association field `join` with other entity?

Comment: Does your JPQL work? Have you tried a JPQL like `SELECT gm.group FROM GroupMember gm WHERE gm.user=:user`? I think this, if it works indeed, is easier to translate to criteria API.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JPA - left join 2 tables without association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20473033/jpa-left-join-2-tables-without-association)

Comment: Thanks very much~ Jens & Nikos!
The answer uses JPQL directly and I have given my JPQL, it works fine.
I hope to use the Creteria API to solve this problem, because this can solve the problem of concat query parameters

Comment: I have given up using the Creteria APIs. I will try to use Querydsl for more flexible queries.

Answer (score 0):

Implementation based on Querydsl:

```
private EntityManager em;

......

User user = ...; // User to query (may be null)
...
QGroup qGroup = QGroup.group;
QGroupMemeber qGMember = QGroupMember.groupMember;

JPAQueryFactory queryFactory = new JPAQueryFactory(em);
JPAQuery<Group> query = (user == null) ?
        queryFactory.selectFrom(qGroup) :
        queryFactory.select(qGroup).from(qGroup).join(qGMember).on(qGroup.eq(qGMember.group));

BooleanBuilder builder = new BooleanBuilder();
if (user != null) {
    builder.and(qGMember.user.eq(user));
}
// if (...) {
//     Other conditions that need to be added to the where clause
// }
query.where(builder);
// Paging condition or something
// ....

List<Group> result = query.fetch(); // search result
```